# JWT Authentication with Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I am developing a Rest Backend with microservices architecture using SpringBoot. To secure the endpoints I have used JWT Token Mechanism. I am using Zuul API Gateway.

If the request has required permission (ROLE from JWT)  It will be forward to the correct microservice. "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" of the Zuul api gateway is as follows.

```
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationConfig config;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConfig jwtConfig() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationConfig();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .anonymous()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(config),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(config.getUrl()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/package/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/dashboard/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/records/**").hasRole("USER");
}
```

In this way I have to write every request authorization part in this class. So I am hoping to use method level security, with "EnableGlobalMethodSecurity".

Problem is how should I connect this security mechanism with other microservices. Because when I added the spring security dependancy to other microservices they behave as different spring security modules. How should I tell to other microservices that work with zuul server security ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all (if i have correctly understood) the security implementation is on proxy? Because the proxy must have only two things to do: filtering and routing...

My microservces application flow, which I have implemented is like in the bellow image:
[image]

And the flow should be like this:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-7

Short brief about flow:

1. On login you should pass the user credentials
2. If the request has the context path "/security" (for example) you should redirect the request to AuthServer (you decide the security implementation)
3. If the user pass available credentials, the AuthServer must return an access_token.
4. Having the access token the user is able to make request to AccountServices(resource services);

*In the AccountServices you must implement a configuration class to decode the access_token and to check if the user has permission to access the resource requested*

Also a good doc you can find here about OAuth2 framework implemented in Spring:http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Some pieces of code:

1. **On AuthService**

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableAuthorizationServer
   public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

   public final static String RESOURCE_ID = "server-resource";

   @Value("${jwt.publicKey}")
   private String publicKey;

   @Value("${jwt.privateKey}")
   private String privateKey;

   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

   @Bean
   public TokenStore tokenStore() {
       return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
   }

   @Bean
   public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
       JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
       converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
       converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
       return converter;
   }

   @Bean
   public TokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer() {
       return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer client) throws Exception {
       client.inMemory()
           .withClient("client")
           .secret("clientsecret")
           .scopes("read", "write")
           .resourceIds("user")
           .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code")
           .authorities("ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
           .accessTokenValiditySeconds(tokenExpire) // one day available
           .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshExpire);
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer server) throws Exception {
       server
           .tokenKeyAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')")
           .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')"); 
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
       endpoints
           .tokenStore(tokenStore())
           .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
           .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
   }
   }
   ```

**About public and private keys:** The *private key* must be known only by AuthServer and the public key must be passed in any service including AuthService. You can generate a public and private key here:http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/ and add these keys in *application.yml* file and pass into the configuration class with `@Value`.

2. **On Resource server**

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableResourceServer
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Value("${jwt.publicKey}")
   private String publicKey;

   @Bean
   public TokenStore tokenStore() {
       return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
   }

   @Bean
   protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
       JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
       converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
       return converter;
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
       resources
           .tokenStore(tokenStore())
           .resourceId("user");
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .csrf().disable()
           .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
   }

   }
   ```

Only thing you must to do is to create a configuration class for resource services (AccountService) to decode the access_token and check if the user has the ROLE to do something... Here you must pass only the **public key** in the same way *application.yml* file.

About  `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` annotation you are able to add `@preauthorize` annotation on controller methods.